# How to make first form disabled if second form is open?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have used this code to open a new form from the current form :

```
 private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      add obj = new add();
      obj.Show();
 }

 private void welcome_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
 {
      Application.Exit();
 }

 private void view_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      view obj = new view();
      obj.Show();
 }

 private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      update obj = new update();
      obj.Show();
 }

 private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      delete obj = new delete();
      obj.Show();
 }
```

In this if i open any form, then the previous form also works as usual.
I want that if a form is open then all other previous form get closed or disabled and sound like a beep on click event of previous button.

Comment: Use ShowDialog() instead of Show();

Comment: @Fendy was just about to suggest it but you were 20 seconds faster than me ;)

Comment: Please will you explain the difference between show and showdialog

Comment: @user2327043 ShowDialog will stop the execution flow of your software, and will wait for the opened form to be closed. The instruction after the ShowDialog will be executed only after the new form get closed.
The Form that have the code that call ShowDialog will be locked, and wont respond do click or user input until you close the new form.

Comment: @Mayur Lol, so fast that I forgot to block it with code tag.

Comment: @Fendy see all the point hunters posting same answers :P LOL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not try Hiding your form and then Close it when the called form is Closed so that it will not stay in memory. Like this.

Let's say in Form1 you click a Button to show Form2

```
 Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
 frm2.Activated += new EventHandler(frm2_Activated);
 frm2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(frm2_FormClosed);
 frm2.Show();
```

Now, this one is when the Form2 showed or is Activated you hide the calling form, in this case the Form1

```
    private void frm2_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide(); // Hides Form1 but it is till in Memory
    }
```

This one when the Called form is Closed in this case Form2 it will also Close Form1 so that it will not stay in the memory.

```
   private void frm2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close(); // Closes Form1 and remove this time from Memory
    }
```

Comment: See my comments above @user2327043, GOD bless.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) instead of [Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show.aspx).

ShowDialog():

> Opens a window and returns only when the newly opened window is closed.

Show():

> Opens a window and returns without waiting for the newly opened window to close.

Answer (score 1):

try to use, this will close your current form.

```
obj.ShowDialog();
 this.close();
```